# How do I access styles object inside React container?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm working on app and I used some ready components from a library. There is functional component where inline styles for divs are taken from object included in this component.

`<div style={styles.chatsContainer} className='ce-chats-container'>`

and this object is below return function

```
const styles = {
    chatListContainer: {
        maxHeight: '100vh',
        overflow: 'scroll',
        overflowX: 'hidden',
        borderRight: '1px solid #afafaf',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        fontFamily: 'Avenir'
    },
    chatsContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '440px',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: '0px 0px 24px 24px'
        
    },
}
```

My question is - how do I access those values so I can change them with onClick?

I tried changing it like this, didn't work ('values read-only')

```
styles.chatsContainer.height = "250px !important"
```

I tried setting state in styles object but there are errors "chatsHeight is not defined"

```
const [chatsHeight, setChatsHeight] = useState("440px")
```

```
chatsContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: chatsHeight,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: '0px 0px 24px 24px'
}
```

Comment: are you using react-jss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate style for that task:

```
const styles = {
    chatsContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '440px',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: '0px 0px 24px 24px' 
    },
    newHeight: {
        height: '250px'
    }
}
```

and then you can create a state that adds your newHeight style on your div when the state is true;

```
const [add, setadd]= useState(false)

const onClickHandler= ()=>{
setadd(!add)
}

 <div style={`${styles.chatsContainer} ${add && style.newHeight}`} className='ce-chats-container'>
```

And dont forget to trigger your onClickHandler function.